# centos 7: all command not found, except cd

Tags: centos, java

I use to run a Minecraft server on Centos 7 with oracle jdk 8.

Sometimes the system crashes and most of the commands are not found, except for example `cd` and the commands that you can see in this image

(I have to press *TAB TAB* to see them):
[image]

I have to do a hard reboot to have all the commands again.

What is making my system crash and lose its commands?

Could be java the cause?

Comment: sounds like your user's PATH environment variable has been stomped on, check the files `~/.bash_profile` and `~/.bashrc` to see if either are attempting to modify PATH and are setting it wrong and removing /bin:/usr/bin from it.

Comment: bash completion should use the $PATH variable, but you could try `/bin/ls` instead of just `ls`. If that _does_ work, then @Rahul is probably right.
you can see your current path with `echo $PATH`.

Answer (score 1):

The [PATH variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)) contains the list of directories where the shell and other programs look for commands. This list is represented with the items joined together with a colon (`:`). For example, a simple PATH would be `/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin`, set with the shell command

```
PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:bin
```

and then when you type the command `ls`, the shell looks for `/usr/local/bin/ls`, then for `/usr/bin/ls`, then `/bin/ls`, and executes the first one it finds.

Evidently you're ending up with a corrupted or missing PATH variable. This cannot be due to a Java program crashing, and it would take extremely convoluted circumstances for this to be due to a Java program misbehaving.

Rather, the plausible explanation is that one of your scripts, perhaps the one that starts the Minecraft server, is clobbering the variable. Check those scripts. In particular, don't use `PATH` as a local variable in the script! There's a convention to use all-lowercase for variables in scripts and all-uppercase for environment variables, which avoids this kind of conflict.